# I need refresh same page use navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, navigation, page-refresh

I need to refresh same screen use navigation drawer in react native.I can refresh screens when navigate other screens.but i clicked same screen link i cannot get any response.How i do this

Comment: can you give more detail maybe you must add some code

Comment: I use  this.props.navigation.navigate(route); to navigate screens.Think if the screen1 is displaying.then i click screen 1 link in navigation drawer i need refresh screen1 screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by following,

In navigation add a parameter (isFromHome),

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: routeName,
      params: { isFromHome: true}
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Then add code in `componentWillReceiveProps()` of your class

eg:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log("#######", newProps.navigation.state.params.isFromHome);
    // Here you will get the parameter every time. By checking the parameter you can achieve your need.
  }
```